# Multi-thread brute-force password breaking algorithm

Tags: c++, multithreading, algorithm, brute-force

I made a multi-threaded program in C++ to break passwords of 7 characters long (lower case characters only) using a brute-force algorithm.

My algorithm is mostly 7 nested for-loops going from a to z and testing every possible combination.

Right now, I'm dividing my work this way :
If I have 3 working threads,
Thread 1 : axxxxxx to ixxxxxx
Thread 2 : jxxxxxx to rxxxxxx
Thread 3 : sxxxxxx to zxxxxxx

So the 3 threads will go on and loop until they find a match.

The main thread will wait for the first thread to return.

My question is : Is this the best way to divide the work between my threads? Do you have any idea on how I could be more efficient?

Also, even if it's not the main part of my interrogation, can you think of a better way than the 7 for-loop iteration?

(Please note that this program is for a school project and not for really cracking passwords)

Comment: *can you think of a better way than the 7 for-loop iteration?* Recursion.

Comment: One sure way to be extremely more efficient is by doing it in the GPU. Look at [oclHashcat-plus](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-plus/).

Comment: @jweyrich: that's a good solution if you're trying to break a hash, but not very useful if you have to actually attempt a login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all keys are equally likely, and if the cost to evaluate a key is the same for every key, and if each thread can expect to be assigned to one CPU without very many interruptions (e.g. your process is the only CPU intensive one running), evenly partitioning the keyspace as you have done will be very efficient.

If some of those assumptions are invalid, a more flexible way to structure the program would be to have one thread (producer thread) hand out key ranges to 1 or more consumer threads for processing.  Once a given thread completes its chunk of work, it would go back to the producer and request a new key range to analyze.

There's some overhead in the producer/consumer pattern, but it is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks, althought the assumptions are valid, I will go on with the producer thread. You made me realize that the point of doing that is not really to reduce the number of tests done (which I was aiming for at first), but to have them done as fast as possible (if a thread gets less interruptions, it will go on with more tests).

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at intel TBB

I would use a `parallel_for` construct on the outerloop and have an atomic variable to signal it being found.

This is pretty trivail using lambdas.

```
tbb::blocked_range<char> rng('a', 'z');
tbb::parallel_for(rng, [&](tbb::blocked_range<char> rng){ 
     for(char a=rng.begin(); a!=rng.end(); ++a)
     {
         //a is your top level character
     }
});
```

The advantage of using TBB is that as mentioned in another answer is that if one thread finishes before another TBB has a work stealing mechanism built it to allow for the fast thread to take work off a slower thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a producer consumer pattern.
Having a ( Thread safe ) queue to produce the password candidate , and consumer threads
That should be more flexible.

For producing the passwords there is nothing wrong with your method, but can be tedious with longer password.

You can use a recursive scheme to produce it.
or an iterative scheme with one loop,  a-z character on the ascii table are sequential, so you can use a base 26 conversion to produce your candidate.